# Spring Data (or JPA) - How to update entity but don't insert if it doesn't exist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a situation where I need to be able to update an entity but be able to throw an exception if it doesn't exist.

The best I could come up with:

```
if (!authorRepository.existsById(1L)) {
    throw new Exception("entity doesn't exist yet!");
} else {
    authorRepository.save(entity);
}
```

Are there other ways? It doesn't seem like JPA provides a way to only do updates, EntityManager.merge() behaves like create or update.

Comment: Check this out https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: Hope you find the solution, Like above user said, you can use native query and check result after to throw Exception. But as a lazy dev, I like your solution

Answer (score 0):

Save method is auto detect in spring boot hibernate and check the id of entity does have exist, update it

Comment: It's good to provide this information but this don't solve the problem. If he use .save() It won't help. So you can recommend some other solution like the owner said: Check before update or write custom native query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).